# I don't understand this Textile Regex

Tags: php, regex, perl

I found the following regex in the PHP code of the Textism Textile:

```
/\b ?[([]TM[])]/i
```

I consider myself to be experienced in reading regexes but this one is a mystery to me. The beginning is easy, but I don't understand why there are two empty character class inside of an already opened character class `[[][]]`?

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: That regex does not compile...

Comment: The regex compiles correctly.

Comment: @lonesomeday, it all depends on the language/tool you're using. It is a valid PCRE. See my answer.

Comment: @BartKiers Indeed, my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a rather cryptic one...

Here's what it means:

```
/     # start regex pattern
\b    # word boundary
 ?    # an optional space
[([]  # char class: either '(' or '['
TM    # literal 'TM'
[])]  # char class: either ']' or ')'
/     # end regex pattern
i     # match case insensitive
```

Some things to note:

- inside a character class, `[` is not special and need not be escaped ( `[([]` is therefor valid!)
- inside a character class, the first character, possibly a special char, need not be escaped ( `[])]` is therefor valid: `]` needs no escape!)

To summarize, it matches `"TM"` case insensitive surrounded by either `[` or `(` and `]` or `)` (they do not need to be  matched: `"[TM)"` will be matched in most cases). I say in most cases, because `\b ?` will cause `"[tm)"` to be excluded from the matches in the demo below because it is preceded by `". "` which does not match `\b ?`:

```
<?php
preg_match_all(
    '/\b ?[([]TM[])]/i', 
    "... [tm) foo (TM) bar [TM] baz (tm] ...", 
    $matches
);
print_r($matches);
?>
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  (TM)
            [1] =>  [TM]
            [2] =>  (tm]
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: but shouldn't  `(` and `)` be escaped?

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. Seems that only works for Perl compatible Regex machines.

Comment: @Krishna No need to escape `(` and `)` inside character class.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: `]`seems to be allowed as the first character of a character class if the regular expression follows the POSIX flavor of regular expressions. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. In PHP, the `eregs_`functions use POSIX while the `preg_`functions use the newer PCRE flavor which does not allow this construct.

So, provided POSIX flavor:

```
[([]
```

is one character class consisting of ( and [ and

```
[])]
```

is another one consisting of ] and ). Most regexp engines would require the second character class to be written

```
[\])]
```

instead.

Comment: But shouldn't that show an error. The 2nd last `]` might be considered as the one closing the prevoius `[`? In Java, that regex is erroneous.

Comment: Right, exactly what confused me.

Comment: You seem to be right. The regexp seems invalid according to Javascript too.

Comment: I think I found the explanation to why `[])]` may sometimes be valid. Please see updated answer.